# Extract a particular div from string

Tags: c#

suppose a huge text data is stored in string variable like

```
<form method="post" action="../Dialog.aspx" id="ctl00">
    <div class="aspNetHidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUBMGRkcTeMEXjXlquwdmAmnkFVfUymwaaSdYr/CV1hV+mxr6A=" />
</div>


<div id="frm">
    <table class="form" border="0"  cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="labeltag">Name:</td>
            <td class="inputtd">
                <input name="ctl01$txtName" type="text" maxlength="100" id="ctl01_txtName" class="inputfield" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="labeltag">Subject:</td>
            <td class="inputtd">
                 <input name="ctl01$txtSubjectject" type="text" maxlength="100" id="ctl01_txtSubjectject" class="inputfield" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="labeltag">Email:</td>
            <td class="inputtd">
                <input name="ctl01$txtEmail" type="text" maxlength="100" id="ctl01_txtEmail" class="inputfield" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="textfield" colspan="2">
                Message:
                <div class="messagefield">
                    <textarea name="ctl01$txtmessage" rows="7" cols="33" id="ctl01_txtmessage" class="message">
                    </textarea>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name="ctl01$btnSubmit" value="Submit" id="ctl01_btnSubmit" class="button" />
                <input type="submit" name="ctl01$btnCancel" value="Cancel" id="ctl01_btnCancel" class="button" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="height:10px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="bottomline" id="loader">

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="aspNetHidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBwKni+1oAuj1kf0MAoWeuckCAqCHyBsC34bOwQQC1cvcnQsC67K1+giML7QhoV19G+plAUvDQ7ade0566ipNfJ+BXR02JW5IIQ==" />
</div>
```

from the above data i just need to extract a particlular div having is called "frm" .

so the whole div and its content will be extracted. i know this can be done with regex but i dont know which patter will work in my case.

i use the code to extract a particular div like

```
 Regex search_string = new Regex("<div.*?id=\"frm\".*?>.*</div>");
        Match match = search_string.Match(outputToReturn);
        string section = match.Groups[0].Value;
```

but section has nothing....match not found. so how to do it.
so please help. thanks

Comment: Does the form tag close? I wanted to use Xml but it's invalid :(.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your string contains html document. In this case you really should use an HTML parser (there are plenty depending on the language).
One that I know of is HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: Even Chuck Norris can't parse HTML with RegEx. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags